# Check for map in list

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a data structure which looks like this:
[image]
I'm trying to write security rules so that only people in the `members` array can write to the document. So far I have this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /organizations/{organizationId} {
      allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write, update: if isOrgAdmin();
      allow write, update, delete: if isSiteAdmin()
    }


    function isOrgAdmin() {
      // ??? 
      return role in resource.data.members == 'Admin'
    }

    function isSiteAdmin() {
      return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.user.isAdmin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to properly check inside an List for a Map with the `role` of `Admin` and the `userRef` of `/users/$(request.auth.uid)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to iterate a list in security rule, and currently no way to extract embedded information from objects in lists using a function like "map" (though there could be a way to do this in the future).  So, what you're trying to do is actually not possible today.

What I'd recommend doing instead is creating a new field that just contains a list of member strings that can be checked using the methods available on list.  You can use [hasAny](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List#hasAny) to check if it contains a member to authorize for access.